# How do you change default java logo in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, icons, joptionpane

I want to know how do you change the icon(the java logo in the title bar) for the JOptionPane box. I am using a swing interface. Please see my sample code below. Wondering why the everytime I run the code , it always display the java logo icon instead of information message icon.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NewClass
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double width, length, area, perimeter;

        String lengthStr, widthStr, outputStr;

        lengthStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the length: ");
        length = Double.parseDouble(lengthStr);

        widthStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the width: ");
        width = Double.parseDouble(widthStr);

        area = length * width;
        perimeter = 2 * (length + width);

        outputStr = "Length: " + length + "\n" + "Width: " + width + "\n" + "Area: " + area + " square units\n" 
                + "Perimeter: " + perimeter + " units\n"; 

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputStr, "Rectangle", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);         

       System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to change that question mark symbol..??

Comment: The icon will also change based on the parent window of the `Component` you supply it

Comment: Hi MadProgrammer Do you have the exact code to display the correct image icon?